# Search Functionality Using GenericRepository Pattern and a SearchService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search, repository-pattern, entity-framework-4.1

I am using the Generic Repository pattern to abstract my EF 4.1 DbContext. I am also using a service layer to query and commit changes to the repository(s). Anyway, what I'm trying to achieve here is allow the user to enter a search phrase into the search bar. Then the SearchService has to query the database to find any TopLevel categories, sub-categories or items that contain the search phrase in their names. On a first glance, I thought that would be a simple thing to do, but apparently things are a little bit more complicated. Here's what I tried to do:

```
    public IList<Item> Search(string searchPhrase)
    {
        var result = new List<Item>();

        var tmp = from c in _repository.GetQuery<TopLevelCategory>(c=>c.Children)
                  where c.Name.Contains(searchPhrase)
                  select c;
        if(tmp.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var c in tmp)
            {
                var children = c.Children;
                foreach (var childCategory in children)
                {
                    result.Concat(childCategory.Items);
                }
            }
        }

        var tmp2 = from c in _repository.GetQuery<ChildCategory>(c=>c.Items)
              where c.Name.Contains(searchPhrase)
              select c;
        if(tmp.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var childCategory in tmp2)
            {
                result.Concat(childCategory.Items);
            }
        }

        var tmp3 = from c in _repository.GetQuery<Item>()
                   where c.Title.Contains(searchPhrase)
                   select c;
        if(tmp3.Count() > 0)
        {
            result.Concat(tmp3);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I know that looks ugly and messed up, but I was just giving it a shot to see if it returns the correct results. Well it didn't, it threw the following exception:

> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   There is already an open DataReader
>   associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

```
Source:

Line 31:          foreach (var childCategory in children)
Line 32:          {
Line 33:                 result.Concat(childCategory.Items);
Line 34:          }
```

So anyway, there has to be a smarter way of doing this... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says you that you have openned DataReader to load top level categories with their children but you are triggering lazy loading in the inner foreach loop. That reaquires another DataReader to open and read lazy loaded items:

```
// Iterate top level categories => fist openned DataReader
foreach (var c in tmp)
{
    // Child category is eager loaded
    var children = c.Children;
    foreach (var childCategory in children)
    {
        // Items are not eager loaded => trigger lazy loading and open new DataReader
        result.Concat(childCategory.Items);
    }
}
```

To solve this you must modify your connection string and add MARS support `MultipleActiveResultSets=true`. MARS is supported at least by SQL Server 2005 and 2008. Another way to avoid this is eager load items as well.

This looks more like task for full text search on database level.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Thanks for the answer. Makes total sense. Yes you are right, I am including the sub-level categories with the top level ones, but I do not know if I can include the items as well. That is because there is no Navigation Property for the Items on the top-level category class. Is there a way around this? And what about MARS, does that have any performance implications?

Comment: MARS is default mode if you let EF to create connection string (for example when you use EDMX). There is no way to avoid MARS in your scenario. There should not be any performance issue in this case. For description of performance related to MARS see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#marsins_topic9

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I added MARS to the connection string and debugged it. Apparently, no items are being retrieved with the Top-Level categories query because I'm not including the Item entity, so I need a work-around that... And by the way, for some reason the query is going inside an endless loop causing a StackOverflowException. Any thoughts?

Comment: What part gets infinite loop?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I'm not really sure, it shows me the error originates from the `@Html.Action("Search", "Item")` call inside my view. But I think it is at the level of the top-level categories...

Comment: Just place breakpoints into your search method to see which part can be reached before exception happens.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I placed a breakpoint at each `if` statement and at the `return` statement. The weird thing is that it hits the return and goes back to the top and keeps doing the same thing over and over...

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Your actually right. I'll try to solve that, and if I couldn't I'll post a question about the issue. Thanks for the help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting may be due to MARS. You just need to enable Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS), just add 'MultipleActiveResultSets=True' into your connection string. Check [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/8cbe2049-53c9-4c02-b040-18ee30fd7800)

1. You can create a view that joins names in TopLevel, Childlevel and items. Then expose this view as an entity. Remember that EF will have issues with views as its designer tried to determine ID field.
2. You can look at [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) in case you think you require better\robust queries capabilities.